# When return E_POINTER and when E_INVALIDARG?

Tags: windows, com, pointers, com-interop

COM interfaces methods can return various `HRESULT` values to signal invalid argument values passed. When do I return `E_POINTER` and when `E_INVALIDARG`?

As I understand if a method receives an index in an encapsulated collection and it is out of bounds that is `E_INVALIDARG`. If a method receives an `Interface**` pointer where it is meant to store a pointer to a newly created object that's `E_POINTER`.

```
HRESULT CImpl::GetItem( long index; Interface** result )
{
    if( result == 0 ) {
        return E_POINTER;
    }
    if( index < 0 || index >= internalArray.size() ) {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }
    *result = CreateWrapperObject( internalArray[index] );
    return S_OK;
}
```

But what if it receives a `WCHAR*` buffer with a file name as an "in" parameter and this `WCHAR*` is null? Is this `E_POINTER` or `E_INVALIDARG`?

Or a method receives a pointer to some struct and is expected to fill the struct through that pointer and this pointer is null - is this `E_POINTER` or `E_INVALIDARG`?

```
HRESULT CImpl::SaveToFile( WCHAR* fileName )
{
    if( fileName == 0 ) {
       return // what to return here?
    }
    //... do actual work here
}

HRESULT CImpl::GetAttributes( Attributes* to )
{
    if( to == 0 ) {
       return // what to return here?
    }
    attributes->IsCool = getIsCool();
    attributes->Color = RGB( 0, 255, 0 );
    return S_OK;
}
```

What are the rules for when to return `E_POINTER` and when `E_INVALIDARG` when checking pointer type parameters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You return `E_POINTER` when the reference to the pointer of an **out** parameter is null, this consider to be an error code that indicates a bug in the program or in the interop layer.

You return `E_INVALIDARG` when there is an application level on with the parameter for example out of range issue or parameter that collide with each other.

In Your case, in `SaveToFile(...)` you should return `E_INVALIDARG` since it is not valid to pass empty file name, and in `GetAttributes(...)` you should return `E_POINTER` (if it's an out param) because you cannot fill the value.

And yes, we all L-O-V-E com :)

Comment: Do you have any doc references?

Comment: Agreed. I'd really like to see a MSDN reference for this. The above makes some kind of sense, but it would be good to have the canonical defition.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer is correct. For example, in VS2010 `<atlcomcli.h>`, in `AtlSetChildSite()` implementation, `E_POINTER` is returned if the `punkChild` parameter is `NULL`, instead according to this answer (if I've understood it correctly), `E_INVALIDARG` should have been returned in that case. I think ATL is a good source of good COM programming practices, so maybe `E_POINTER` should be returned in the general cases of invalid (e.g. `NULL`) pointers. But frankly I'm not sure either, and I agree some MSDN official reference would be good.

Comment: To add to the confusion, in the same `<atlcomcli.h>` header, in `CComPtr<IDispatch>` specialization, in `PutProperty()` implementation body, `E_POINTER` is returned if `pVar` (`_In_ VARIANT*`) is `NULL`, but `E_INVALIDARG` is returned if `p` (`_In_ IDispatch*`) is `NULL`.

Comment: I was wondering too, and the closest answer I could find on MSDN is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485842(v=vs.85).aspx. Since an out param / retval needs a valid pointer to "return" the value, seems to me Shay is as right as anyone could be without hard and fast rules of COM.